# Show Disk Space Used for all Tables - Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

We are transitioning across to Azure SQL Data Warehouse - and an issue that's been highlighted is the need to change some smaller tables from Round-Robin / Hash-distributed to Replicated to improve performance.

MS Design Guidance ([See Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/design-guidance-for-replicated-tables)) suggests one criteria for this decision is Tables that take up less than 2Gb Disk Space. i.e. these tables *could* be made into Replicated tables. They suggest using DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED to determine this.

I can run this against the whole DB, or one specific table, but i'd really like to get a list of all tables and the space used (preferably in MB) - but it's beyond me.

A lot of google searching either gives me the two basic commands I already know (against the whole DB / against 1 table) or give me SQL Server queries that don't run against Azure DW - e.g. using **sys.allocation_units** - which is not supported in Azure DW.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, did you  find anything in the end?

Comment: I just opened an MS Docs issue asking for this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/94217

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just [directed](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/94217#issuecomment-1154124042) to [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-overview#table-size-queries) that provides a pretty solid solution to this problem.

In particular, create a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.vTableSizes
AS
    WITH base
    AS (
           SELECT
                   GETDATE()                                                                                     AS [execution_time],
                   DB_NAME()                                                                                     AS [database_name],
                   s.name                                                                                        AS [schema_name],
                   t.name                                                                                        AS [table_name],
                   QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name)                                                   AS [two_part_name],
                   nt.[name]                                                                                     AS [node_table_name],
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY
                                          nt.[name]
                                      ORDER BY
                                          (
                                              SELECT
                                                  NULL
                                          )
                                     )                                                                           AS [node_table_name_seq],
                   tp.[distribution_policy_desc]                                                                 AS [distribution_policy_name],
                   c.[name]                                                                                      AS [distribution_column],
                   nt.[distribution_id]                                                                          AS [distribution_id],
                   i.[type]                                                                                      AS [index_type],
                   i.[type_desc]                                                                                 AS [index_type_desc],
                   nt.[pdw_node_id]                                                                              AS [pdw_node_id],
                   pn.[type]                                                                                     AS [pdw_node_type],
                   pn.[name]                                                                                     AS [pdw_node_name],
                   di.name                                                                                       AS [dist_name],
                   di.position                                                                                   AS [dist_position],
                   nps.[partition_number]                                                                        AS [partition_nmbr],
                   nps.[reserved_page_count]                                                                     AS [reserved_space_page_count],
                   nps.[reserved_page_count] - nps.[used_page_count]                                             AS [unused_space_page_count],
                   nps.[in_row_data_page_count] + nps.[row_overflow_used_page_count] + nps.[lob_used_page_count] AS [data_space_page_count],
                   nps.[reserved_page_count] - (nps.[reserved_page_count] - nps.[used_page_count])
                   - ([in_row_data_page_count] + [row_overflow_used_page_count] + [lob_used_page_count])         AS [index_space_page_count],
                   nps.[row_count]                                                                               AS [row_count]
           FROM
                   sys.schemas                           s
               INNER JOIN
                   sys.tables                            t
                       ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
               INNER JOIN
                   sys.indexes                           i
                       ON t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
                          AND i.[index_id] <= 1
               INNER JOIN
                   sys.pdw_table_distribution_properties tp
                       ON t.[object_id] = tp.[object_id]
               INNER JOIN
                   sys.pdw_table_mappings                tm
                       ON t.[object_id] = tm.[object_id]
               INNER JOIN
                   sys.pdw_nodes_tables                  nt
                       ON tm.[physical_name] = nt.[name]
               INNER JOIN
                   sys.dm_pdw_nodes                      pn
                       ON nt.[pdw_node_id] = pn.[pdw_node_id]
               INNER JOIN
                   sys.pdw_distributions                 di
                       ON nt.[distribution_id] = di.[distribution_id]
               INNER JOIN
                   sys.dm_pdw_nodes_db_partition_stats   nps
                       ON nt.[object_id] = nps.[object_id]
                          AND nt.[pdw_node_id] = nps.[pdw_node_id]
                          AND nt.[distribution_id] = nps.[distribution_id]
                          AND i.[index_id] = nps.[index_id]
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   (
                       SELECT
                           *
                       FROM
                           sys.pdw_column_distribution_properties
                       WHERE
                           distribution_ordinal = 1
                   )                                     cdp
                       ON t.[object_id] = cdp.[object_id]
               LEFT OUTER JOIN
                   sys.columns                           c
                       ON cdp.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
                          AND cdp.[column_id] = c.[column_id]
           WHERE
                   pn.[type] = 'COMPUTE'),
         size
    AS (   SELECT
               [execution_time],
               [database_name],
               [schema_name],
               [table_name],
               [two_part_name],
               [node_table_name],
               [node_table_name_seq],
               [distribution_policy_name],
               [distribution_column],
               [distribution_id],
               [index_type],
               [index_type_desc],
               [pdw_node_id],
               [pdw_node_type],
               [pdw_node_name],
               [dist_name],
               [dist_position],
               [partition_nmbr],
               [reserved_space_page_count],
               [unused_space_page_count],
               [data_space_page_count],
               [index_space_page_count],
               [row_count],
               ([reserved_space_page_count] * 8.0)              AS [reserved_space_KB],
               ([reserved_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000       AS [reserved_space_MB],
               ([reserved_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000000    AS [reserved_space_GB],
               ([reserved_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000000000 AS [reserved_space_TB],
               ([unused_space_page_count] * 8.0)                AS [unused_space_KB],
               ([unused_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000         AS [unused_space_MB],
               ([unused_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000000      AS [unused_space_GB],
               ([unused_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000000000   AS [unused_space_TB],
               ([data_space_page_count] * 8.0)                  AS [data_space_KB],
               ([data_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000           AS [data_space_MB],
               ([data_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000000        AS [data_space_GB],
               ([data_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000000000     AS [data_space_TB],
               ([index_space_page_count] * 8.0)                 AS [index_space_KB],
               ([index_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000          AS [index_space_MB],
               ([index_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000000       AS [index_space_GB],
               ([index_space_page_count] * 8.0) / 1000000000    AS [index_space_TB]
           FROM
               base)
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        size;
```

Then, this "Table space summary" query provides a list of tables and how much space each is currently using (among other information):

```sql
SELECT
    database_name,
    schema_name,
    table_name,
    distribution_policy_name,
    distribution_column,
    index_type_desc,
    COUNT(DISTINCT partition_nmbr) AS nbr_partitions,
    SUM(row_count)                 AS table_row_count,
    SUM(reserved_space_GB)         AS table_reserved_space_GB,
    SUM(data_space_GB)             AS table_data_space_GB,
    SUM(index_space_GB)            AS table_index_space_GB,
    SUM(unused_space_GB)           AS table_unused_space_GB
FROM
    dbo.vTableSizes
GROUP BY
    database_name,
    schema_name,
    table_name,
    distribution_policy_name,
    distribution_column,
    index_type_desc
ORDER BY
    table_reserved_space_GB DESC;
```

Here's a sample execution against one of my databases showing the table names sorted by space used.

[image: Sample query execution showing used space by table]

Comment: Have you proof-checked that the sum of all this columns equals to the total size of your database?